# How to change text color in Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

Is there a way to change the text and background color in the Mac terminal? I'm trying to change the text color to red and see if there are more backgrounds to change too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to: Terminal>Preferences>Profiles.
(Or hit Cmd+, and click the Profiles tab)

From there, you can modify colour themes.

Comment: Great - can you close the question and mark my answer as accepted please :) (Trying to increase rep!).